# Raw HTTP1.1 request implementaion in Java not getting terminated

Tags: java, network-programming

I have implemented httpClient by using the code from the below link. I am able to get the html repose and program is getting terminated when the HTTP request is of version 1.0.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html

If I change the version to 1.1 , the reponse is printed,but program is not getting terminated even after that. Please mention the changes and suggest the changes.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HttpClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      // The host and port to be connected.
      String host = "www.google.com";
      int port = 80;
      // Create a TCP socket and connect to the host:port.
      Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
      // Create the input and output streams for the network socket.
      BufferedReader in
         = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter out
         = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
      // Send request to the HTTP server.
      out.println("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1");
      out.println();   // blank line separating header & body
      out.flush();
      // Read the response and display on console.
      String line;
      // readLine() returns null if server close the network socket.
      while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      }
      // Close the I/O streams.
      in.close();
      out.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP keepalive is on by default in 1.1. So the response isn't terminated by end of stream: it is terminated by the Content-length or the chunking if used.

See RFC 2616. If you're implementing HTTP you need to know it all.